# Underlying explanation of Neural-Network basedtime-series future-value prediction

Tags: neural-network, time-series, training

I have confusion related to Feed Forward Neural Network.

I train my network for time-series prediction, and it is working great and as expected.
I know how NNs train and to predict i.e. there is neuron's weights and biases training that takes place. But I am still unable to fathom the underlying behaviour of the network in time series.

*For example, given a **single** data point, how does my network know that it has to predict up or down in the next point? For example, if the input value is (let's say) **10.5**, how does my network knows to predict **10.6** and not **10.4**. **How given a single data point, the network is predicting the next point accurately?***

[image: Output of time series]

The following is the summary of my FNN. Please note that I have one input feature and one output value;

[image: NN summary]

[image: the NN depiction]

Comment: Could you give details on your NN structure please ? Input size, type of neurons used, ...

Comment: Sure. I have added the details (if it helps). I can add further details as well. Giving some more info: I have one input feature which is the cellular data-traffic and I'll get the output for the same but the output is the future (one-time instance in this case) data-traffic prediction.

Comment: The predictions of the model almost seem to good to be true. How many data points have you trained your model on and have you split the data into a training and test dataset (i.e. are you predicting on out of sample data points)?

Comment: @Oxbowerce is right concerning the prediction, it seems to good to be true :).